# .com domain transfer failing

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I'm trying to transfer one of my .com addresses between registrars. I'm down as the owner contact (confirmed working) and the losing registrar is down as the tech and admin contact.

Last week I received an email stating that the domain transfer had been rejected by the losing registrar. I contacted the losing registrar and they denied that. My money from the winning registrar was refunded and I was told to try again. I've initiated the transfer again and received confirmation of pending transfer, I gave the correct EPP code and confirmed the transfer.

Currently the status on the domain is set as OK, should it not be transfer pending? According to my name.com transfer page if the transfer is not authd in 5 days it will auto transfer anyway. I don't believe this will happen. Name.com have been really helpful but they can't really do much more now. The losing registrar is not being helpful hence me turning here.

What can I do to make sure the domain transfers? The domain transfer is set to expire on the 17th.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain has finally been moved. It runs out that there was/is a problem with the name.com mail servers. The losing registrar received 25 emails in the space of 2 minutes with the transfer request, all of which were out of date. I've now moved the domain to 123-reg which worked first time.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, a transfer could only be denied by a registrar for very specific reasons detailed here:
https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2012-02-25-en

Answer (score 0):

We'll your best best is to contact them once everyday to make sure the transfer goes through. I mean you have 5 days from now.

Usually when I do transfers it takes maybe max 20 minutes with Godaddy.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

We had this kind of problem many time with a registrar I won't name here, because of their poor service. When this happen to one of our customer, we simply call the hosting and ask them to set the Admin Informations to our email/name, they can't refuse as **you** own the domain, once you can access the Admin e-mail you can accept the transfer yourself.

After that, I would also recommend you to contact the Registration Autority for that extension, and tell the that the registrar has made it difficult for you to transfer out.

I don't know the Autority for the .com name tho, for the .ca it's cira.ca.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps for a successful domain transfer:

1. Unlock the domain.
2. Make sure private registration is turned off.
3. Change the administrative contact email to an email you can control.
4. Get the EPP code.
5. Request a transfer from the new registrar giving them the EPP code.

The reason for #3 is because as soon as that request is put in an email will be sent to the administrative contact email address with a link to click to verify the domain transfer.

It can take up to 7 days to transfer the domain, the reason is because they wait that long to see if there is a transfer dispute.

Good luck!